# Problem with equals sign in doc \changes

Tags: makeindex, doc

When documenting a class/package with the doc package (or some derivative), what's the best way of including a literal equals sign in the text of a `\changes` command? Since `=` is used as a special character in the entries, anything before it is stripped.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=10pt,varwidth=25em]{standalone}
\usepackage{doc}
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\changes{v1}{2020-01-01}{Before=After}
\PrintChanges
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: General: After ... 1]

Wrapping in braces doesn't work. The best I've come up with is to define a macro
in the preamble and then include the command sequence as a string, like this:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=10pt,varwidth=25em]{standalone}
\usepackage{doc}
\RecordChanges
\def\MyEquals{=}
\begin{document}
\changes{v1}{2020-01-01}{Before\string\MyEquals\space After}
\PrintChanges
\end{document}
```

But is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeindex` has a set of special characters, and `gglo.ist` sets `=` as the `actualchar`. You can quote that `=`, so that `makeindex` will treat it literally, using the `quotechar`.   To quote a character for `makeindex` you just prepend it with the `quotechar`, which in `gglo.ist` is `!`, so you can write:

```
\changes{v1}{2020-01-01}{Before!=After}
```

Running `makeindex -s gglo.ist -o test.gls test.glo` on that file you get:

> [image]